# how to fix Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, indexof, lastindexof

i have this situation:

```
if (image.indexOf("/bob/") != -1 || image.indexOf("/grabs/") != -1 || image.indexOf("/") == image.lastIndexOf("/")) {
    alert('success');
}
```

in IE8 i get `Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'`

i could probably use something like `$.inArray("/bob/", image)`, but im not sure about `lastIndexOf`

any ideas how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a regex, something like

```
if(/\/(bob|ginger|grabs)\//.test(image) || /^[^\/]*\/$/.test(image)){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it with jQuery, you could do

```
$.inArray("/", image, $.inArray("/", image)) === -1
```

i.e. look for the next occurrence of `/` after the first occurrence. This assumes that `/` is always present in the array. If not, then the equivalent would be

```
var index =  $.inArray("/", image);
if (.... || (index === -1 ||  $.inArray("/", image, index) === -1)) {
   // ...
}
```